# Flutter How to make two columns in Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a Container, inside you need to make two columns. In one column there will be icons with texts, and in another there will be one icon in the center.
More details on the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC9bZ.png)

Comment: Show the code snippet you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.mail_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Text('title'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.mail_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Text('title'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.mail_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Text('title'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.mail_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Text('title'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Photo'),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Comment: I put your code, it works fine, but the left text with icons go to the center, how can I do everything in the left margin?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @user266322. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code, which will help you attain what you want to achieve. **Also, I have replaced the photo with the real image, to give you a feel about how the image works. However, it is NetworkImage(), it uses web images, if you want to use the local image, then do use AssetImage()**

```
       Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: 350.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail_outline,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Text('title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ]
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail_outline,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Text('title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ]
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail_outline,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                      Text('title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ]
                  )
                ]
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80.0,
                    width: 80.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-pink-flower-anemones-fresh-260nw-1028135845.jpg')
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
```

**RESULT**

[image: Resultant Image]